# Can I create a separate table for a single Collection property using Entity Framework code first?

Tags: database, entity-framework, orm

I have a class `Foo` with an `ICollection<string>`. To be able to store this through Entity Framework, I have created a class `Bar` with an `Id` and `Value` property. Entity Framework creates a table for `Bar` with a foreign key column to `Foo`. This works well.

The problem is that I have a whole bunch of classes with such a `ICollection<string>`. I converted them all to `ICollection<Bar>`. The result however is that the `Foo` table now contains a foreign key column for every class that has an `ICollection<Bar>` (10+).

While I understand that it's necessary to do this to have those relationships work in the database, the database diagram doesn't get more intuitive this way.

I was thinking that, like in a many to many relationship, I would like to have a table in between each of those relationships. For example,

- a table `Foo_Bar` with two columns: `Foo_Id` and `Bar_Id` for the relationship between `Foo` and `Bar` and another table `Baz_Bar` with `Baz_Id` and `Bar_Id`.

To achieve this, I can create a sub class of `Bar` (e.g. `FooBar`) for every relationship; change the collection to use those (e.g. `ICollection<FooBar>`); and let EF create the database using the table per type (e.g. by decorating `FooBar` with `[Table("Foo_Bar")]`) approach for these types. But I would like to prevent having to create all these empty classes.

I wonder if it is possible to somehow specify this behaviour just based on the property. Something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Table("Foo_Bar")]
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

On a side note: If this approach is a bad idea in the first place, don't hesitate to let me know :).

Comment: if you want a many to many relation you have to setup it: `modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>.HasMany(x => x.Bars).WithMany()`. Then you'll have jt join tables.

Comment: Isn't it created like so by default? Say `Foo` and `Baz` have `Bars` collection. `Bar` has `Foos` and `Bazs` collection. The result would be 5 tables, `Foos`, `Bars`, `Bazs`, `FooBars` and `BazBars` ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra well it is not really a many to many relationship. All the `Bars` are basically distinct so every `Bar` only has one `Foo` or `Baz`. So now EF has created a `Bar` table with a foreign key for each class that has an `ICollection<Bar>`.

Comment: @tschmit007 That works! Is it also possible with an annotation?

Comment: @MatthijsWessels, isn't it @tschmit007 solution is still many to many, but with independent association (no `Foos` and `Bazs` collection on `Bar`) ? the generated tables are still 5 tables I think..

Comment: @YuliamChandra yes the result after specifying that it is a many to many relationship using the fluent api, is 5 tables. That's what I wanted. But my `Bar` doesn't have collections of `Foos` and `Bars`. Did you mean that I should add those to get the desired result?

Comment: Okay, so that you confirm you need many to many relationship, but you don't want to have any collection property in `Bar`, that's still achievable using fluent api like tschmit007 mentioned. By adding the collection you don't have to configure it in fluent api, the [EF convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx) will figure it out that it's a many to many relationship, if you don't need that collection, but still want to have many to many relationship, use fluent api then `HasMany(x => x.Bars).WithMany(/*leave empty*/)`

Comment: @YuliamChandra Yes that's right. The tricky thing I guess was that it's not really a many to many relationship, but I want EF to create the table structure as if it was.

Comment: I'm not familiar with annotation, may by this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships) may help you.

Comment: @YuliamChandra, I agree convention should do. But do not use convention if is magic for you because if _Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic_ you must understand a techno before using it. Beside I like to think that explicit relations make the code more resistant to convention changes.

Comment: I have the same question with perhaps slightly different goals here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632096/relate-multiple-tables-to-single-general-purpose-table-in-entity-framework-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to summarize comments:

what you want (i.e.: 5 tables) is a many to many relation for Entity  Framework.

By conventions you get it by setting a collection on both entities

```
Foo {
    ICollection<Bar> Bars
}

Foo {
    ICollection<Foo> Foos
}
```

if you don't want the reverse collections (Foos) then you have to setup the relation by the fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>.HasMany(x => x.Bars).WithMany()
```

AFAIK there is no annotation allowing to reach this last result by using the Annotations.

You then have to handle by hand the unicity of Foo for a Bar. A solution may be a unique constraint on the Bar Key of the join table created by EF.

Comment: As my goal was to unclutter the `Bars` table from having 10+ foreign key columns of which mostly only one would be non-null, the collections approach would only move the clutter to the `Bar` class which would then have 10+ collections of which mostly only one would have exactly one item. I would have preferred my table per type approach over that. However the fluent API approach fits my needs nicely. An annotation on the `Bars` property in each referencing class would have even been better, but looking at the docs, that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: you may also try inheritance: `abstract class base { ICollection<Bar> Bars}`, then `Foo : base`, `SomClass : base` and use a table per concrete type [TPC](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) approach, but you still need the fluent API as default behavior is TPH.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how that would change anything. Don't you mean TPT instead of TPC? That would make the `Bars` table only have one FK: the PK of the `bases` table. Not a bad idea as that would avoid all the clutter, although such a hierarchy is a bit weird in a domain model.

Comment: What I was thinking with inheritance and TPT before was: `class BazBar : Bar {}`,  `class FooBar : Bar {}`, `class Foo { ICollection<FooBar> Bars }` and `class Baz { ICollection<BazBar> Bars }`. The `FooBars` and `BazBars` tables will be the link in the same way as with a many-to-many relationship with the added benefit that the `Bar_Id` is unique. The reason I didn't want that is because I would have to create all these extra empty classes.

Comment: I mean TPC is a way to implement the table Bars with only one FK column referencing a base record. You can thus get you 0-N to 1 cardinality. O or N bar record for the base record, 1 and only 1 base record for each bar record. Please read the linked article and the limitation of TPC.

Comment: I am familiar with the article and I still think you mean TPT :). TPC doesn't give you a table for `base` which is not a concrete type while TPT does exactly that. Even if `base` was not abstract, it would just create an extra unrelated table and `Bars` would still have a FK for every referencing type. From the article: "(..) the SQL schema is not aware of the inheritance; (..) I have to emphasize that there is no relationship between the database tables, except for the fact that they share some similar columns."